# Estimates for $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

Assume $x,y\in[0,1]$ and $|x-y|<\frac{1}{4}$

Any idea how to see that these inequalities hold:

$|\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}|^2<|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|$ for $x,y\in[\frac{1}{4},1]$

and

$|\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}|^2<|\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1-y}|$ for $x,y\in[0,\frac{3}{4}]$

I already tried some simple calculations but couldn't see it. Maybe there is a simple trick?

Comment: It seems the inequalities are equivalent by change of variables $x=1-x'$ and $y=1-y'.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc True, if $x \in [\frac{1}{4},1]$ then $x'\in [0,\frac{3}{4}]$ and we can see that the terms on the left and right are equivalent. So it is enough to see that one of the inequalities holds. Thanks!

Comment: Jensen's inequality comes to mind...

Comment: I played around with the inequality but didn't come to the derivation of the inequality. For example: 
$\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is concave function.  with Jensen
$\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}\leq\sqrt{(x-y)(1-(x-y))}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality is untrue in general as it fails when $x,y$ both approach $1$. For example, take $(x,y)=(0.999,0.9)$ which satisfies $x,y\in[\frac14,1]$ and $|x-y|=0.099<\frac14$ but gives

$$\left|\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}-\sqrt{y\left(1-y\right)}\right|^{2}=0.0720\nless0.0508=\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right|$$

As has been established in the comments, the second inequality is equivalent to the first under the transformation $(x',y')=(1-x,1-y)$, so neither inequality is generally true.

To assess where the first inequality *does* hold, consider the sign of the function defined by $$f(x,y)=\underbrace{\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right|}_{\text{RHS}}-\underbrace{\left|\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}-\sqrt{y\left(1-y\right)}\right|^{2}}_{\text{LHS}}$$
$$=\left[\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}\sqrt{y\left(1-y\right)}\right]-\left[\sqrt{y}+x\left(1-x\right)+y\left(1-y\right)\right]$$

where we dispense with the absolute value signs by expanding the square via $|z|^2=z^2$ and assume WLOG that $x>y$. The function $f$ is continuous, so solving the inequality amounts to finding its zeros and determining its sign near them. Since $f$ is algebraic, this is equivalent to solving the polynomial given by clearing its radicals.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much for the answer! I got this inequality from a research paper and therefore I believed it was true, but couldn't find a proof for that.